# How to handle different form submission in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have four separate section where I would like to handle form submission in my page (Section #1 and #2 are shown when the user agent is in mobile):

Section #1 (mobile:

```
<div id="mSearchB" class="mSearchTextHolder">
    <div class="mSearchInnerTextHolder">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="txtMSearch" id="txtMSearch" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Image for #1:

[image]

Section #2 (mobile):

```
<div class="brClear loginHolder floatLeft">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="txtUsername" class="txtUsername styledTB floatLeft" />
</div>
<div class="floatLeft">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwPassword" class="txtPassword styledTB floatLeft" />
</div>
<div class="floatLeft">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="Login" class="styledBtn logBtn floatLeft lightLinks">Login</a>
</div>
```

(Image for #2 hasn't been built yet but similar to #1)

Section #3 (non-mobile):

```
<div class="searchBox">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" id="searchB" />
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="Search"><img src="theImages/searchWhite.png" alt="Search" title="Search" class="searchImg" /></a>
</div>
```

Section #4 (non-mobile):

```
<div class="brClear loginHolder">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="txtUsername" class="txtUsername styledTB floatLeft" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwPassword" class="txtPassword styledTB floatLeft" />
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="Login" class="styledBtn logBtn floatLeft lightLinks">Login</a>
</div>
```

Image for #3 and #4:

[image]

For #3 and #4, if I click on the search icon all three textboxes goes blank of the placeholder.

I haven't placed any `form` tag around any of the one above because the asp.net page already has one auto inserted on page creation.

How do I handle each submission separately, so clicking or hitting enter on one textbox doesn't submit the entire form for all?

Comment: Is this WebForms?  (It sounds like it, based on how you describe the `form` tag.)  If so then you don't make them separate.  In the server-side code you would have different click handlers for different buttons, but it's all one form causing one post-back.

Comment: Yes it is a web form.

Comment: So, make every button a server side control and then use each click separately? What about the `Enter` on separate textboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't placed any form tag around any of the one above because the asp.net page already has one auto inserted on page creation.

That sounds like WebForms.  In which case, basically, you *don't* separate your form posts.  The entire page is one big form and any post-back triggering event is going to submit the entire form to the server.

The way it's done in WebForms is to have separate server-side click event handlers for separate buttons.  So if "sub form 1" has `Button1` and "sub form 2" has `Button2` then each would have their own server-side handlers:

```
void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Button1 was clicked, handle it here
}

void Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Button2 was clicked, handle it here
}
```

As for the "default" click action for pressing enter on other controls or things like that, you can wrap each "sub form" in a `Panel` control and set [its `DefaultButton` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I looked at this post (http://forums.asp.net/t/1423067.aspx?More+than+one+form+on+a+page+) which also helped. Thanks

Comment: Can I add the `action` inside the button click handler?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  What is the `action`?  If you're referring to the `action` attribute of the `form`, a WebForms page always posts back to itself.  You shouldn't need to worry about the `action` attribute of the `form` tag.

Comment: This is the first time I am setting up forms so that is why I was asking. Yes, the "action" attribute of the form.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: If you can use MVC instead of WebForms I think you'll find it a lot more familiar to your existing knowledge of HTML.  WebForms likes to do things its own special way :)  But basically you can think of the entire page as a single form and you're just handling the events of different controls in the server-side code.  So instead of different forms with different actions, you'd have different event handlers with different logic therein.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not really well versed in MVC in aSP.net coming from HTML/CSS. I did take your advice and was able to get the Login form to atleast work and will work on the rest the same way. Thanks. Up voted and accepted answer.